# Remove element from perl join array result

Tags: regex, perl

My problem:

```
@array = (possible text,
          text surrounded with round brackets,
          text without brackets,
          text surrounded with round brackets,
          possible text);

$line = join(' ', @array);
```

I want to delete, if there is any text before the first bracket and any text after the last bracket of the join result (possible text).
Thanks.

real code:

```
my (@lines, $line, $anchor, $left, $right, $parent, $elem);
($anchor) = $tree->look_down(_tag=>"span", class=>"txt");
if ($anchor) {
    $elem = $anchor; 
    my ($product, @tmp);
    while (($elem = $elem->right()) &&
            ((ref $elem) && ($elem->tag() ne "table"))) {
        @tmp = get_all_text($elem);
        push @lines, @tmp;
        $line = join(' ', @tmp);
```

Comment: Equally important: post example input data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
$line =~ s/.*?(\(.*\)).*/$1/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a syntax error.

You should fix that first, then figure out how to further process $line.

Maybe you forgot to make the assignment to @array a qw?

If so, then the code below will cut out the text before the 1st "text surrounded"
and the text after the last "text surrounded".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use warnings;
#use strict;

@array = qw(possible text,
          text surrounded with round brackets,
          text without brackets,
          text surrounded with round brackets,
          possible text);

$line = join(' ', @array);

$line =~ s/.*?(text surrounded with round brackets)/$1/;
$line =~ s/(.*text surrounded with round brackets).*/$1/;
print "$line\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$line =~ s/\A[^(]+//;
$line =~ s/[^)]+\z//;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the array, building an index of where you see the first bracket and the last bracket, then extract the corresponding slice.

```
my @array = ('possible text',
   '(text surrounded with round brackets)',
   'text without brackets',
   '(text surrounded with round brackets)',
   'possible text');

my ($first, $last);
for (my $i = 0; $i < $#array; ++$i) {
    next unless $array[$i] =~ m/^\s*\(/;  # maybe adapt this regex
    $first = $i;
    last;
}
for (my $j = $#array; $j > 0; --$j) {
    next unless $array[$i] =~ m/^\s*\(/;  # tweak this too then
    $last = $j;
    last;
}

my $line = join (' ', @array[$first..$last]);
```

This isn't as elegant as a `map` or a `grep`, I'm afraid.

**Edit:** Originally had a single loop to find both `$first` and `$last` but two separate loops is more efficient.  This also depends on the structure of your data; if there isn't a lot of it, this optimization is obviously not very important.  On the other hand, if there is really a lot of data, you might be able to optimize this even further.